# How to Filter DataGridView on basis of multiple options?

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, datagridview

I have a gridView control named dgvAllBikes. On form load i load dgvAllBikes. Now i want to filter this gridView which is dgvAllBikes on basis of three options and a search button.

1) CC

2) Model

3) Color

When i click on search button i want to filter dgvAllBikes on basis of these three options.

Here is my LoadGrid Code

```
 private DataTable LoadGrid()
    {

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetAllBikes", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            dtAllBike = new DataTable();

            dtAllBike.Load(r);

        }
        return dtAllBike;
    }
```

i have declared DataTable in class level

```
string CS;
    protected DataTable dtAllBike;
    public SaleBike()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BikeDB"].ConnectionString;
    }
```

Here is the picture
[image]

Here is the code for btnSearch.

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
        bs.DataSource = dgvAllBikeDetails.DataSource;
        bs.Filter = dgvAllBikeDetails.Columns["CC"].HeaderText.ToString() + " LIKE '%" + tbCCSearch.Text + "%'";
        dgvAllBikeDetails.DataSource = bs;
```

It filter on basis of CC but i am not able to bind the other two option. Your help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `OR` or `AND` operator to create a filter that works on multiple values.

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
    bs.DataSource = dgvAllBikeDetails.DataSource;   

    string filter = "";

    // Check if text fields are not null before adding to filter. 
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbCCSearch.Text)) 
    {
        filter += dgvAllBikeDetails.Columns["CC"].HeaderText.ToString() + " LIKE '%" + tbCCSearch.Text + "%' ";
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbModelSearch.Text)) 
    {
        if (filter.length > 0) filter += "OR ";
        filter += dgvAllBikeDetails.Columns["Model"].HeaderText.ToString() + " LIKE '%" + tbModelSearch.Text + "%' ";
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbCCSearch.Text)) 
    {
        if (filter.length > 0) filter += "OR ";
        filter += dgvAllBikeDetails.Columns["Color"].HeaderText.ToString() + " LIKE '%" + tbColorSearch.Text + "%' ";
    }

    bs.Filter = filter;
    dgvAllBikeDetails.DataSource = bs;
}
```

Comment: Superb.. Love it .. Thank you very much bro

Comment: Glad I could help! =)